# C sharp error and concat strings doesn't work

Tags: string, concatenation

Why this simple program doesn't work?

```c
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp7
{
    class Program
    {
       
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string name;
            string all;
            for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("enter name");
                name = Console.ReadLine();
         
                Console.WriteLine(name);
                all =string.Concat(all, name);

            }
            Console.WriteLine("all the names are ");
       //     Console.WriteLine(s1);

        }
    }
}
```

It gives an error and does not cascade all strings?
Thanks

Comment: ok succeeded this way

Comment: using System;

namespace ConsoleApp7

{
    class Program
    {
       
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string name = "", all="";
           
            for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("enter name");
                name = Console.ReadLine();
         
                Console.WriteLine(name);
                all =string.Concat(all, name, " ");

            }
            Console.WriteLine("all the names are "+ all);


        }
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the value of variable `all`. Here's a sample that works:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    string name;
    string all = null;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("enter name");
        name = Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine(name);
        all = string.Concat(all, name);

    }
    Console.WriteLine("all the names are ");
    Console.WriteLine(all);
}
```

Note, however, that there are no separators added beween the three names. If someone would enter "one" and "two" and "three", for instance, then the output would be "onetwothree". Maybe you want something different, maybe not.